# custom Listview data is overriding while fetching json data setting on adapter

Tags: android

i am using volley library for web api call and retrieving json data using for loop and setting that data on custom listview but listview only show  two values of that data like if my loop run for 4 times only 2 or 4 numbered value is shown on listview .
Below is my code for fetching values from json data.

details=new ArrayList();

```
    depart_adapter = new Result_dep_adapter(Result.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, details);

    return_adapter = new Result_ret_adapter(Result.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, details);
    departlist.setAdapter(depart_adapter);
    returnlist.setAdapter(return_adapter);
```

try {

```
                     for (int k = 0; k < response.length(); k++) {
                     custom_result=new Custom_Result();
                         Log.i("response",","+ response.length());
                         JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(k);
                         JSONObject flight = obj.getJSONObject("Flights");
                         JSONArray array = flight.getJSONArray("Segments");
                         for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                             JSONObject depart = (JSONObject) array.get(i);




                                 String departdate_time = depart.getString("DepartureTime");
                                 String arrivedate_time = depart.getString("ArrivalTime");
                             Boolean returnflight=depart.getBoolean("IsReturnFlight");
                                duration=depart.getString("FlightDuration");
                             Log.i("segments",","+returnflight);
                                 JSONObject Airline=depart.getJSONObject("Airline");
                                 String Airline_code=Airline.getString("Name");
                                 JSONObject Airlinename=depart.getJSONObject("MarketingCarrier");
                                 String name=Airlinename.getString("Name");
                                    Log.i("Airline code", Airline_code);
                                 String[] departtime = departdate_time.split("T");
                                  String[] arrivetime = arrivedate_time.split("T");
                                 if (!returnflight) {
                                     String ddate = departtime[0];
                                     String dtime = departtime[1].substring(0, 5);
                                     Log.i("time", dtime);
                                     String duration = depart.getString("FlightDuration");
                                     String Adate = arrivetime[0];
                                     String Atime = arrivetime[1].substring(0, 5);


                                     custom_result.setDepart_date(ddate);
                                     custom_result.setDepart_time(dtime);
                                     custom_result.setArrive_date(Adate);
                                     custom_result.setArrive_time(Atime);
                                     custom_result.setDep_duration(duration);
                                     custom_result.setDep_Airline_name(name);
                                     custom_result.setDep_Airline_code(Airline_code);



                                 }else{
                                     String Rdate = departtime[0];
                                     String Rtime = departtime[1].substring(0, 5);//return depart time
                                     Log.i("time", Rtime);
                                     String return_duration = depart.getString("FlightDuration");
                                     String ARdate = arrivetime[0];
                                     String ARtime = arrivetime[1].substring(0, 5);

                                     custom_result.setRet_arr_date(ARdate);
                                     custom_result.setRet_arr_time(ARtime);
                                     custom_result.setRet_dep_date(Rdate);
                                     custom_result.setRet_dep_time(Rtime);
                                     custom_result.setRet_duration(return_duration);
                                     custom_result.setRet_Airline_name(name);
                                     custom_result.setRet_Airline_code(Airline_code);

                                 }



                             }
                             String stops = flight.getString("Stops");
                             JSONObject Fare = flight.getJSONObject("Fare");
                             String published_fare = Fare.getString("PublishedFare");
                             custom_result.setStops(stops);
                             custom_result.setPrice(published_fare);

                             details.add(custom_result);





                         }
```

I am new to android please help me ..
Thank you

This my adpater code

private class ViewHolder
    {
        ImageView Airline_logo;
        TextView Airline_code,dep_time,dep_arr_time,dep_stops,dep_duration,
                 dep_price;

```
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder=null;
 //  custom_result=Custom_Result.getCustom_result();
    custom_result=getItem(position);
    LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if(convertView==null)
    {
        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.result_listview,null);

        holder=new ViewHolder();
       holder. Airline_logo=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dep_airlines_image);
        holder.Airline_code=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dep_airline_code);
        holder.dep_time=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dep_depart_time);
        holder.dep_arr_time=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dep_arrive_time);
        holder.dep_stops=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dep_stops_info);
        holder.dep_duration=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dep_duration);
        holder.dep_price=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dep_airline_price);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else
    {
        holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
    String imagename=custom_result.getDep_Airline_code().toLowerCase();

  String path="drawable/"+imagename;

  // String logo=path.toLowerCase();
  // String PACKAGE_name=getContext().getPackageName();
int imageresource=context.getResources().getIdentifier(path, null, context.getPackageName());
if(imageresource==0)
    {
imageresource=R.drawable.flight_icon;
        }
    Drawable image=context.getResources().getDrawable(imageresource);

  // holder. Airline_logo.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(),image));
    holder.Airline_logo.setImageDrawable(image);
    holder.Airline_code.setText(custom_result.getDep_Airline_name());
    holder.dep_time.setText(custom_result.getDepart_time());
    holder.dep_arr_time.setText(custom_result.getArrive_time());
    holder.dep_stops.setText(custom_result.getStops());
    holder.dep_duration.setText(custom_result.getDep_duration());
    holder.dep_price.setText(custom_result.getPrice());

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Cant understand your problem, what are you trying to achieve and what are you getting?

Comment: I want to set my listview with all data values that i am getting from json data.

Comment: But only few values is shown on listview  not all the values

Comment: Your parse and adapter code looks OK, can you try finding where it is overriding with the debugger?

Comment: Nothing find on debugger as well.

Comment: customresult.setdeptime value in logcat is showing 11:20 and 22:30,but only 22:30 value is showing on listview

Comment: Can you post the missing part of the adapter code?

Comment: The constructor part?

Comment: was looking for the getCount()

Comment: No I hadn't use getcount method.

Comment: getCount implementation is necesary... how is your code working... really this is starting to look like you are not using a listview for what is intended

Comment: My adapter class extends arrayadpter and I never used getcount method for adapter class. As I am new to android so I am missing most of the important things

Comment: Can please tell me its use or purpose or refer some links for that. And that can be the Reason my values are overidding?

Comment: Please implement what i describe in my answer and tell me when you are using BaseAdapter instead of ArrayAdater (next time post your full code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2 as the layout for the row.

[That layout](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_2.xml) only has 2 textviews so it cant show more than 2 values.

If you need to show more things you need to create your custom adapter from the BaseAdapter Class.

Then in the getView() method you can draw the row with anything you need.

Hope this helps.

Comment: No, When my inner loop(i ) run for 4 times it only show me the 2 or 4th values. first or 3rd values override by the 2nd or 4th value.

Comment: so i want to know how i add my data to list so that it shows all json data values

Comment: Im really trying to understand you, really... You have a object model that stores all the data you need and it is working right? or the problem is with storing the model??.

Comment: my sorry ,if you are getting confuse with my question

Comment: Are you missing more text on each row or more rows in the list?

Comment: yes, when my i retrieve json values and store it through model class object . on logcat iam getting all data i want but on listview it only shows 1st or 3rdvalue(if my  inner loop lenght is 4)

Comment: If you are missing values of each row then the problem is with the layout of the adapter, why did you think my answer was not correct?

Comment: rows value missing means , the shown values is showing twice on listview

Comment: so, may be my model class values are overriding when loop run again  and save the values on object.

Comment: i want to stop that overriding